# Android Memory Problem

Tags: ram

So I had a problem with my memory today. I recently rooted my Samsung Galaxy Trend (GT-S7392) with RootGenius 1.8.7 I rooted my phone because I wanted to transfer apps to my ext sd card since Samsung Galaxy didn't support transferring apps to ext sd.

After rooting my phone, everything was fine, except I found out that my internal memory is full, so I checked it what was wrong with it and I saw that my system memory is taking all my space on internal memory. I dont really know what was the cause of it and my question is how to fix this?

-Total Space: 4.00 GB

-System Memory: 4.00 GB

-Applications: 210 MB

Sorry for my grammar, english is not my first language :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By any chance, could you download [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) and then open it, and run the command "df" without quotes and show the screenshot of output? It will help getting clearer picture of memory distribution.

Comment: In addition to what @JaskaranbirSingh said, if possible, you may post the screenshot of default main view of the app [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)(<1MB).

Comment: Hi there. I have provided the screenshots here http://m.imgur.com/eq5k7Yt,1I2aZk8,FylwCPP

Answer (score -1):

The best solution would be format your mobile. There can be too much waste data in system memory.Or clean the system by using some cleaning app. There can be any number of reason behind this. BTW I would say that your mobile is outdated. In android, 512 ram and 4gb memory is not gonna do anything. It is gonna create problem again and again.

Comment: Hello Kumar Thank you for replying. I have downloaded a cleaning app and started cleaning but it still does not work. I also did the factory reset and nothing happened. This is only my temporary phone because i left my original phone back in japan and i will return to japan after two years of college here. Anyway, I cannot download anything on my brower because of the memory problem but the weird thing is i can download apps from play store

Comment: Vivek, that is kinda... not an appropriate answer. Cleaner apps are worst thing to use in android. They.Dont.Work. Their only purpose is to extract money using ADs and stuff. Refer this-> [Why cleaner apps are useless](http://www.howtogeek.com/171424/why-memory-optimizers-and-ram-boosters-are-worse-than-useless/) And the topic isnt related about ram and performance hardware, so lets skip that ;)